# DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory - Concurrency - At which point does the number of threads per queue start to increase?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, amazon-sqs

[DefaultMessageListenerContainer documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) states:

> Dynamic scaling of the number of concurrent invokers can be activated by specifying a "maxConcurrentConsumers" value that is higher than the "concurrentConsumers" value. Since the latter's default is 1, you can also simply specify a "maxConcurrentConsumers" of e.g. 5, which will lead to dynamic scaling up to 5 concurrent consumers in case of **increasing message load**, as well as dynamic shrinking back to the standard number of consumers once the **load decreases**.

It's not clear in the documentation, what actually is increased load? 100/1k/1m queued messages?
At which point does the number of threads per queue start to increase? When should "maxConcurrentConsumers" be reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing fancy, basically "as soon as all threads are busy processing a message" and a message is queued.

If you can allocate one more to process a queued message (i.e. `maxConcurrentConsumers` has not been reached), then an extra thread is allocated to process it. This therefore defines the maximum number of concurrent threads processing messages.